# Azure notification not working in IOS

Tags: azure, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, azure-mobile-services

I have followed the document

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-get-started-push/

android it working fine, but for iOS device got registered successfully , that i am seeing in Service Bus Explorer. but notification not receiving in IPhone. Please help me on this issue...

Comment: For the tutorial did you mean: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-ios-get-started-push/ ?  The one you pointed to was for legacy (not using notification hubs)

Comment: @phillipv thankyou sor reply. i tried with notification hub alone. even that also not working. but it works fine in Android devices, may be some error in iOS certificates.